# Lines + Markers not working in Dash Scattergeo Plot

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I’ve created a scattergeo plot in Plotly which is rendering fine, including displaying line + markers [Plotly screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqJqX.png)

However when i call this graph through Dash I can't get the lines + markers to work - it will only show markers

[Dash screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSpqt.png)

When I use mode = lines I get lines in Dash, however evening reversing the options won't show markers + lines

My Code:

```
dict(type='scattergeo',
    locationmode='country names',

    lon = [From_lon,To_lon],
    lat = [From_lat,To_lat],
    mode='lines + markers',
    opacity = max(min(1,float(df.iloc[i]['Volume']/2000)),0.1), 
    #opacity = min(1,float(df.iloc[i]['Volume']/1000)), 
    name = df.iloc[i]['ALP From'] + "->" + df.iloc[i]['ALP To'] + " " + df.iloc[i]['Volume'].astype(str),
    hoverinfo="name",
    line = dict(color=df.iloc[i]['Marker_col'],
                width = max(2,df.iloc[i]['Volume']/2000)
    )
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you try `mode='lines+markers'`, i.e. without the spaces?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the spaces from `"lines + markers"` and use `mode="lines+markers"` instead